# precompile App_LocalResources in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

My **web-application** project (not "web-site" project) is translated to 15 different languages using the ASP.NET's built-in resource engine - which means I have tons of *.aspx.resx files in the "App_LocalResources" folder.

All these resources are precompiled by ASP.NET when I first launch the application and it takes a lot of time. I mean A LOT. 5-10 minutes. I have to wait 5-10 minutes every time I make some tiny change to my code, just to see how it works.

**Is there any way to pre-compile these resource in Visual Studio?** Changing the "Build Action" for all these resx-files to "Embedded resource" does not work :( (or I'm doing it wrong?)

PS. I know I can write a batch file that will launch aspnet_compiler.exe with a lot of command-line-arguments and manually compile the app with all the resources, but thats a "hack". I need a documented "Visual Studio"-way to achieve this. Cause I have a setup-project for this app in the same solution, that picks up the "project output" of this web-app (and it won't pick-up any manually precompiled files I made)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a post-build event that will launch the ASP.NET compiler
Aspnet_compiler -p "src_folder" -v / "dest_folder"

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to put your localized resources to external assembly.

Comment: ASP.NET won't automatically pick resources from some random assembly. It has to be "App_LocalResources" folder.

Comment: @jazbit: Not random but special way registered

Comment: @abatishchev do you that "special way"? :)

Comment: @jazbit: I with I knew! I try to google something interesting because your question is actual for me too

Comment: yeah... я тоже гуглю... I found this question on StackOverflow, but its unanswered :(( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643131/can-i-combine-local-resources-in-satellite-assemblies

Comment: @jazbit: привет Лондону! :) what about implementing own `IResourceProvider`? For example, http://fredrik.nsquared2.com/viewpost.aspx?PostID=157&showfeedback=true leads to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy4kkhe0.aspx but it contains no description for `resourceProviderFactoryType` attribute